# Indexer query error empty values

Tags: magento2, database, query, indexer

When I run the indexer I get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

This is caused by the following:

> LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tad_price` ON tad_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_price.attribute_id =  AND tad_price.store_id = 0

The attribute_id is empty. I've been searching the database for an errors but can't seem to find any.
Can anyone help me out of give me some advice?

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND tad_price.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tas_price` ON' at line 13, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, tad_tax_class_id.value) AS `tax_class_id`, IFNULL((IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value)), 0) AS `orig_price`, IFNULL((IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) < IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value))), 0) AS `price`, IFNULL((IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) < IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value))), 0) AS `min_price`, IFNULL((IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) < IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value, tad_price.value))), 0) AS `max_price`, tp.min_price AS `tier_price`, tp.min_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>    CROSS JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg`
>    CROSS JOIN `store_website` AS `cw`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id
>    INNER JOIN `store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
>    INNER JOIN `store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tp.website_id = cw.website_id AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 97 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 97 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 133 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 133 AND tas_tax_class_id.store_id = cs.store_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tad_price` ON tad_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_price.attribute_id =  AND tad_price.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tas_price` ON tas_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_price.attribute_id =  AND tas_price.store_id = cs.store_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tad_special_price` ON tad_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_price.attribute_id =  AND tad_special_price.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tas_special_price` ON tas_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_price.attribute_id =  AND tas_special_price.store_id = cs.store_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_from_date.attribute_id = 79 AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_from_date.attribute_id = 79 AND tas_special_from_date.store_id = cs.store_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date` ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_to_date.attribute_id = 80 AND tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date` ON tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 80 AND tas_special_to_date.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id = 'simple') AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1)
>   Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and pp_default.store_id=0
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_we' at line 3, query was: SELECT`rp`.*, IFNULL(pp1.value, pp_default.value) AS`default_price`FROM`catalogrule_product`AS`rp
>    `INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity`AS`e`ON e.entity_id = rp.product_id
>    INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity`AS`pp_default`ON pp_default.entity_id=e.entity_id AND (pp_default.attribute_id=) and pp_default.store_id=0
>    INNER JOIN`catalog_product_website`AS`product_website`ON product_website.product_id=rp.product_id AND product_website.website_id = rp.website_id AND product_website.website_id=1
>    LEFT JOIN`catalog_product_entity`AS`pp1`ON pp1.entity_id=e.entity_id AND (pp1.attribute_id=) and pp1.store_id=1 ORDER BY`rp`.`website_id`ASC,`rp`.`customer_group_id`ASC,`rp`.`product_id`ASC,`rp`.`sort_order`ASC,`rp`.`rule_id` ASC

Comment: Can you post your code lines?

Comment: It is just a plain Magento installation. No modules. added the full query/error